# New to JavaScript RegEx - Selecting Middle Word from Three-Word String

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very new to JavaScript's RegExp library, and need help selecting the middle word from a three-word string.
For example:
`Saturday October 1` would return `October`.

My (feeble) attempt was `\s.*\s`, but this returned `(space)October(space)`. However, I need the spaces to be omitted from the match.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to trim the string

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks, but this is for a Computer Science class assignment, and the directions specify to use RegExp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^.*?\s(\w+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/44

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and then refer to group index `#1` for the match result.

```
var r = 'Saturday October 1'.match(/\s(.*)\s/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[1]); //=> "October"
```

Or as stated in the comments, trim the match result.

```
var r = 'Saturday October 1'.match(/\s.*\s/);
if (r)
    console.log(r[0].trim()); //=> "October"
```

But wouldn't `split`ting the string be easier in this case?

```
var r = 'Saturday October 1'.split(' ')[1];
console.log(r); //=> "October"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to trim the returned value or

```
var match = 'Saturday October 1'.match(/\s(.*)\s/); 
var text = match && match[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first matching group to have exactly the middle word

```
\s+(\b.*)\s+
```